# JoomGallery with Avatar Slide Galleria Unlimited

Tags: joomla2.5, slide, galleria, avatar

I am using 
Joomla 2.5
JoomGallery 2.xx
I have downloaded and installed Avatar Slide Galleria Unlimited

I am trying to use Avatar Slide Galleria Unlimited on top of JoomGallery.

In JoomGallery when i am setting up:

Detail view --> General Settings --> Open Original Image in

I see many installed plugins except of avatar.

Any suggestion how can i make "JoomGallery" to work with "Avatar Slide Galleria"

any help would be much appropriated.

Answer (score 0):

With the Unlimited Edition, Avatar Slide Galleria is module extensions for Joomla to slide images in from JoomGallery. It's not JoomGallery plugin.
Galleria will only be called by Joomla site but not the JoomGallery.
You cuold add the module into your site and set it to show JoomGallery Images.

SETUP MODULE
Login to Joomla Control Panel page as Administrator

Choice Extension>Module Manager.
Click New.
Choice Avatar Slide Galleria.
Set the parameter for your Module silde image from Joomgallery

Avatar slide galleria can slide JoomGallery images by categories and sub categories.
You can chosse categories or sub categories for Galleria to slide them.

Thanks